# Linear regression result not as expected, following simple test

Tags: swift, algorithm, linear-regression, cgpoint

I have a function, [borrowed from Ray Wenderlich](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Linear%20Regression), for linear regression across a series of points:

```
extension Array where Element == CGFloat {
    // A closed form solution
    fileprivate var average: CGFloat {
        return self.reduce(0, +) / CGFloat(self.count)
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    fileprivate static func multiply(_ a: [CGFloat], _ b: [CGFloat]) -> [CGFloat] {
        return zip(a,b).map(*)
    }

    static func linearRegression(a: [CGFloat], b: [CGFloat]) -> (_ a: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let sum1 = CGFloat.multiply(b, a).average - a.average * b.average
        let sum2 = CGFloat.multiply(a, a).average - pow(a.average, 2)
        let slope = sum1 / sum2
        let intercept = b.average - slope * a.average
        return { x in intercept + slope * x }
    }
}
```

I've added a simple test to ensure it gives me the result I'm expecting:

```
class CGFloatExtensionsTests: XCTestCase {
    func testLinearRegression() {
        let points = [
            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2),
            CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1),
            CGPoint(x: 3, y: 4),
            CGPoint(x: 4, y: 3)
        ]

        let linearRegression = CGFloat.linearRegression(a: points.map({$0.x}), b: points.map({$0.y}))

        let y1 = linearRegression(1)
        let y2 = linearRegression(3)

        XCTAssertEqual(y1, 1, accuracy: 0.0001)
        XCTAssertEqual(y2, 3, accuracy: 0.0001)
    }
}
```

So I'm placing points equally, and expect that a linear regression line should pass right through the middle of those points. Both of these tests fail, however, with the first expected result being `1.6` and the second being `2.8`.

To demonstrate.. blue are the points. Green is my expected line of Linear Regression, and yellow is the actual line of Linear Regression.

[image]

Are my expectations/understanding of this incorrect? Is the algorithm incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is wrong. The [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) is the line

```
y = a * x + b
```

which minimizes the sum of squares of the difference between the observed
y-values and the interpolated y-values, i.e. (a, b) are determined such that

```
sum( (a * xi + b - yi)^2, i=1,...,n)
```

is as small as possible. For your values

```
(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3)
```

this is the line

```
y = 0.6 x + 1
```

for which the sum of square differences is 3.2. For the line `y = x` the
sum of square differences is larger, namely 4.0.

Comment: You've lost me.

Comment: @Andrew: Short answer: your program is correct. – If you determine the *vertical* distance from each of the 4 points to the regression line and add the squares of those distances, then the result is minimal for the yellow line.

Comment: I'm still completely lost. I don't have much of a math background. Could you tell me what I need to do, in code, to get the correct simple linear regression line?

Comment: @Andrew: What you compute *is* the correct simple linear regression line.

Comment: So it’s my assumption that it should follow the green line which is wrong?

Comment: @Andrew: The green line would be the [“orthogonal regression”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression#Orthogonal_regression).